Understanding Proof of Lemma 5.6.8 of Mathematical Logic by Chiswell & Hodges
In Mathematical Logic by Chiswell and Hodges, there is part (a) of the lemma below.
My question is on Case 1, subcase (iii) in the proof. The authors say $t$ is a variable not among $x_1,...x_n$, and then that $t[T]_A = t_A = t[S]_A$. But... isn't $t_A$ NOT defined in this subcase? By Definition 5.6.2, the element $t_A$ is only defined for a CLOSED term $t$... In this subcase, $t$ is not closed because it is a variable that is not being affected by the substitutions.

Lemma 5.6.8:
Let $\sigma$ be a signature and A a $\sigma$ structure. Let $t_1,...,t_n$ and $s_1,...,s_n$ be closed terms of LR($\sigma$) such that for each $i$ $(1\leq i \leq n)$, $(s_i)_A = (t_i)_A$.
(a) Let $t$ be a term of LR($\sigma$) with distinct variables $x_1,...,x_n$. Then
$t[t_1/x_1,...t_n/x_n]_A = t[s_1/x_1,...s_n/x_n]_A$
Proof:
We write $T$ for the substitution $t_1/x_1,...t_n/x_n$ and S for the substitution $s_1/x_1,...s_n/x_n$. The proof of (a) is by induction on the complexity of the term $t$.
Case 1
$t$ has complexity $0$. There are three subcases.
(i) $t$ is a constant symbol $c$. Then $t[T]_A = c_A = t[S]_A$
(ii) $t$ is $x_i$ with $1 \leq i \leq n$. Then $t[T]_A = (t_i)_A = (s_i)_A = t[S]_A$
(iii) $t$ is a variable not among $x_1,...x_n$. Then $t[T]_A = t_A = t[S]_A$
Case 2
$t$ has complexity $k>0$, where (a) holds for all terms of complexity $<k$. Then $t$ is $F(r_1,...r_m)$ for some terms $r_1,...r_m$ all of complexity $< k$.
We have $t[T]_A = F(r_1[T],...,r_m[T])_A = F_A(r_1[T]_A,...,r_m[T]_A) = F_A(r_1[S]_A,...,r_m[S]_A)=...=t[S]_A$
(where the first equation is by Definition 5.4.4(b), the second by Definition 5.6.2(b), and the third by induction hypothesis.)


Yes, if the interpretation is not defined for open terms, the result of the substitution in case that $t$ is a variable different from those considered by the two substitutions will be undefined in both cases.
For sure, whatever the result is, it is not affected by the substitutions.
Compare with Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum & Wolfgang Thomas, Mathematical Logic (Springer 3rd ed, 2021) Coincidence Lemma, page 34.
